# VBScript and Xpath excluding duplicates

Tags: xml, xpath, vbscript, msxml3

I am trying to pull names from an XML Document using a vbscript.

**XML Document structure**

```
<Aliases>
    <Alias PartyType="DF" CaseID="000000" NameType=""> Name Name</Alias>
    <Alias PartyType="DF" CaseID="000000" NameType=""> Name Name</Alias>
    <Alias PartyType="DF" CaseID="000000" NameType=""> Name Name</Alias>
    ...
</Aliases>
```

the XML File might have 100 rows with the same name coming from several different CaseID's because for this part of my vbscript I am trying to pull all the *different* Names from all cases, but here is the issue, I don't want to return duplicates.

is there a way to do this with an xPath Expression or should I try to do this with VBScript?

**UpDate**

using the answer below I am now getting the following error

> msxml3.dll: Expected token ')' found ':'.
>
> Aliases/Alias[@PartyType='DF' and not(./text() = preceding-sibling-->:<--:*/text())]

I tried

```
Aliases/Alias[@PartyType='DF' and not(./text() = preceding::/*text())]
```

thinking that the application might be using MSXML.net and not MSXML3
and it still gave me the same error.

???

Comment: you phrase it like it would be *either* VBScript or Xpath, but I hope you are using the MSXML parser in VBScript, don't you?

Comment: I am not sure, I would think so. I am writing vb script to extract the Data from the XML to insert it into a form in a program. the data is extracted from a SQL Server Data Base using a dll written in C# to insert it into the XML that the application uses to store information, then the application runs the VBScript that I am writing to extract the injected information.  I am still new to the applications I just started here about 3-4 months ago.

Comment: you are not sure? Please show us the relevant code snippet you already have to read the data.

Comment: I am marking the answer from FKDev because I believe that will do what I need it to do via the Xpath Query. I haven't been able to test this in the project I am working on because of the weekend and because I have run into an issue with other parts of the project that have nothing to do with this issue. but I am almost certain that FKDev has given me the answer that I am looking for with this question.

Comment: the application does use MSXML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like This maybe

```
/Aliases/Alias[not(./text() = preceding-sibling::*/text())]
```

(I haven't tried it but it should work)

Comment: will this only work for the element directly preceding it or for all elements preceding?  does that make sense?

Comment: should probably be `following-sibling`? so that I can start at the top and work my way down, but then i would have to figure out a way to skip them if they matched a previous element

Comment: preceding-sibling will give you all the preceding elements on the same level.

Comment: ok! I see it now. TGIF I think I just have `Code Eye` today! when I am finished writing the code I will test it and see if it works for me.  I think it will though! +1

Comment: should it be `/Aliases/Alias[(./text() != preceding-sibling::*/text())]`  ?

Comment: msxml3 is an old thing is it ? Shouldn't you be using msxml6 ? I've tested the xpath here : http://www.online-toolz.com/tools/xpath-editor.php. It seems to work.

Comment: it's an application that wasn't created in house. so I can't update it or anything because it's hooked into everything else.

Comment: it also seems to work with my Full XML Document. but just not inside the application that I am working with

Comment: In that case, you might combine XPath with code. For example get all the aliases via XPath, then use code to iterate and remove duplicates.

Comment: I create a .dll that pulls the information and then injects it into an xml document and then the form pulls that information using vb script. so I am going to try the xPath Query that you gave me inside the .dll to remove the duplicates instead of inside the vbscript.  so this will be C# stuff (something I am more Familiar with)

Comment: thank you for your help, I finished the application I was working on, the XPath that you gave me worked out wonderfully, I took out the `not` part so that I could grab the duplicates and remove them from what I had already.